Error when trying to use the `sudo apt update` command
I am trying to use the sudo apt update command, but I keep getting the following error:
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY E88979FB9B30ACF2

As a result, I am not able to proceed with the update.
How do I get around this error?
